MAC address incomplete when connecting via static ip
n my company I have a setup where i want to have the options to connect with a raspi over dhcp when using LAN inside and a static fallback ip when connecting the raspi to my PCI ethernet port for testing in a thermal chamber. Therefore I configured two system connections on the raspi with Network Manager. DHCP with the higher priority works just fine meaning i can change the Network Manager config but I can't connect with the raspi over the static ip.
Looking at the arp table gives the following:
$arp -a  
_gateway (192.168.1.1) at < incomplete > on enp4s0  
? (192.168.1.71) at < incomplete > on enp4s0  

On the raspi the Network Manager has these two config files:
[connection]  
id=01DHCP  
uuid=90088f39-750d-42df-b883-e55a1ec9feea  
type=ethernet  
autoconnect-priority=1  
autoconnect-retries=0  
interface-name=eth0  
permissions=

[ethernet]  
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]  
dns-search=  
method=auto

[ipv6]  
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy  
dns-search=  
method=auto

[proxy]

--------------------------------------------------------------------

[connection]  
id=02STATIC  
uuid=5db0c823-bc0c-4a0a-8889-2fe4256920bc  
type=ethernet  
autoconnect-priority=-2  
autoconnect-retries=2  
interface-name=eth0  
permissions=

[ethernet]  
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]  
address1=192.168.1.71/24  
dns=8.8.8.8;  
dns-search=  
method=manual

[ipv6]  
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy  
dns-search=  
method=auto

[proxy]

--------------------------------------------------------------------

and the pci port of my laptop has the following config

[connection]  
id=Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1  
uuid=ae4d451c-85cf-34c4-be8f-80e3e68ba950  
type=ethernet  
autoconnect-priority=-999  
interface-name=enp4s0  
timestamp=1725874079  

[ethernet]

[ipv4]  
address1=192.168.1.10/24,192.168.1.1  
dns=8.8.8.8;  
ignore-auto-dns=true  
method=manual

[ipv6]  
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy  
method=auto

[proxy]

The incomplete MAC address made me think something is wrong with the ip configuration. I tested the hardware (eth cable and the port) and it works fine. I also tried flushing the DNS server on the raspi but it also showed no effect.
Thanks for any type of help

ARP failure is very much not a DNS problem, it's some two layers below that. Do you have HDMI or serial console on the Pi, to verify that it is in fact switching to the 02STATIC profile when connected directly to the laptop?

I am only connected to the Pi with the ethernet cable of my port so I can't really tell whether 02STATIC is on. But at one point during setting up the IP configuration i was able to connect with the static IP. The Pi is built inside a casing where the only possible connection is via ethernet apart from disassemblying it

Connect it via LAN and check the system logs (same or previous boot) to see if that happens – and write down its IPv6 link-local address (the one that starts with "fe80"; I might set the profiles to addrgen=eui64 to keep it stable). Alternatively, try to ping ff02::1%enp4s0 from your laptop and see if the Pi responds?

I was not entirely sure where to look. but under journalctl -u NetworkManager.service it didn't seem as Networkmanager does something when booting with static ip. However pinging worked perfectly fine and there was 0% package loss over ethernet port

Does the ping command return the Pi's fe80:: address specifically? (i.e. not your own or some other device's on the LAN?) Try ssh'ing to root@fe80::whatever%enp4s0 and see if that works, while directly connected.

It returns the Pi's address specifically and i can connect via ssh. When i check the Network Manager connections with nmcli con show 01DHCP is flagged as activating while 02STATIC is down.


01DHCP is flagged as activating

It seems you have configured the profile to retry forever so it'll always be 'activating' even when there's no DHCP. According to the docs:

$ nmcli con edit foo
nmcli> describe connection.autoconnect-retries

The number of times a connection should be tried when autoactivating before giving up. Zero means forever, -1 means the global default (4 times if not overridden). Setting this to 1 means to try activation only once before blocking autoconnect. Note that after a timeout, NetworkManager will try to autoconnect again.

Only one profile can be in use for a given interface, so 02STATIC will be down while 01DHCP is trying to activate (and vice versa).
